# World Stock Markets that went up in 2008

Tags: finance, stock-market, financial-markets

We all know that the US stock market(s) collapsed in price in 2008, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_bear_market_of_2007%E2%80%9309.

I was wondering what countries' stock markets went up throughout this period.

Include things like frontier markets and not just developed countries.

I cannot find a data source online.

Comment: I am not looking for individual stocks/sectors

Comment: I think there a quant finance stack exchange, that is probably a better place to ask. Getting free equity market data is generally difficult, but there may be academic databases. In any event, you should just phrase your question to where there are free equity index data (and first look to see whether that was already asked). What happened in 2008 is not really the issue.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk I think what I was trying to aim for was what equity markets were highly unaffected by a substantial crash in the US. Ie were somewhat isolated from the US economy.

Comment: I worked in fixed income, but I doubt that any equity market made it through 2008 OK. The Financial Crisis was global, and global trade and finance stopped dead. Maybe some countries with high inflation had their stock markets go up, but that might not mean much. I think you would need a good source of developed/emerging market data, to test that, and that data is rarely free. The finance site here might have more information. People like myself do interest rate questions, but those are borderline economics/finance.

Comment: I dislike your question very much as the whole idea about equities is that they don't do well in a financial crisis. There are countless **other types of assets**, which did very well in 2008, but asking for equity markets that did well in 2008 is like asking what oceans don't contain any water. It's theoretically possible to have an equity market, which is isolated enough from the global economy, but this market would probably have a lot of idiosyncratic risk and wouldn't be a good standalone investment or hedge against crises.

Comment: @Andras Your point is quite amusing. What other asset classes did well (even small ones)?

Comment: @Jurassic sovereign fixed income, certain derivatives like CDS

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend. E.g Australia did very well in the crisis of 2008

See: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007–2008#](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%932008#)

Comment: Im not seeing the bit about australia in that link

Comment: The ASX went down in 2008??? See https://www.asx.com.au/about/historical-market-statistics.htm